# Conditional probability for a monkey to randomly write a sentence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

We all know the statement that a monkey, typing random keys, given enough time, will type anything we want.
Say what I want is the sentence: "This is cool".

There are 12 characters, if the monkey's keyboard has 30 keys (the actual number is irrelevant), there will be $\frac{1}{30^{12}}$ probability to write that sentence.

Let's change the problem, now I am going to assume that, as soon as the monkey types the first correct letter, the "T" (let's forget about upper/lower case) a special software on the keyboard will automatically type a "T" before each new keystroke, so that, as soon as the monkey types the "h", she will actually be typing "Th". Then, the software will automatically pre-pend "Th" to any new keystroke, so that, as soon as the monkey types an "i", we will see "Thi", at which point the software will always prepend "Thi" and so on.

This goes on until we get "This is coo" which is pre-pended to any new keystroke, and when the monkey randomly hits an "l" I have the sentence "This is cool".

My question is, what is the probability that the monkey will type "This is cool" if she types on a keyboard with this special software installed?

My intuition is suggesting something similar to $\frac{1}{12*30}$ but I am not sure if that is correct, or how to prove it.

In particular, I believe in the first case we should on average wait for $\frac{1}{30^{12}}$ keystrokes, how long should we wait in the second case?

Comment: You can look at your problem as a Markov chain with 13 states (start state + one per letter to press). You're at the starting state and you're trying to get to the last state. In each state except the last, you have $p$ probability of advancing to the next and $1-p$ probability of staying in place.

Comment: @Rchn Would you like to expand your comment into an answer?

Comment: @user First of all 10 charecters in "this is cool."

Answer (score 1):

The question about the probability isn't well-defined because you haven't specified the number of attempts. In the first scenario, without the special software, you stated the probability for a single attempt; this probability is the same in the second scenario because the software isn't of any help in a single attempt.

However, the number you suggested does relate to the solution: It's the reciprocal of the expected number of keystrokes. Each letter is typed correctly with probability $\frac1{30}$, so the expected number of keystrokes to get one letter right is $30$. Once she gets a letter right, the letters she types effectively become attempts at the second letter, as the software prepends the correct first letter. Thus, the probability to get the second letter right is again $\frac1{30}$, and the expected number of keystrokes to get it right is again $30$. This works the same for all $12$ letters, so by [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) the expected total number of keystrokes is

$$12\cdot30=360\;.$$

This is all assuming that you're only counting the monkey's keystrokes. Since you write that the software “types” the correct letters, these might also be counted as keystrokes. In that case, each attempt at the $k$-th letter would require $k$ keystrokes, so the expected total number of keystrokes would be

$$
30\sum_{k=1}^{12}k=\frac{30\cdot12\cdot(12+1)}2=2340\;.
$$

Comment: I am not sure what you mean that "the software “types” the correct letters, these might also be counted as keystrokes". My explanation was probably confusing. By keystroke I only mean the monkey's keystrokes, in that case are you suggesting the probability is $\frac{1}{12*30}$ by linearity of expectation (which I will look up)?

Comment: @user: I mean exactly what I wrote: "The question about the probability isn't well-defined because you haven't specified the number of attempts. In the first scenario, without the special software, you stated the probability for a single attempt; this probability is the same in the second scenario because the software isn't of any help in a single attempt." Since I think the question about the probability isn't well-defined, I'm not suggesting any value for it.

Comment: I am sorry if I don't understand. In the first example, I do not need to specify the number of attempts, the probability is $\frac{1}{30^{12}}$, which represents the number of seconds I need to wait on average (assuming the monkey types one keystroke per second). Under the same assumptions, how long will I have to wait on average in the second example with the modified software?

Comment: @user: You seem to be equating the reciprocal of an expected waiting time with a probability. This is valid if the time is defined as a number of attempts, where each attempt has the same success probability; in this case the expected waiting time is indeed the reciprocal of the success probability of the individual attempts. However, in your scenario, the waiting time is defined as a number of keystrokes, and the individual keystrokes can't be interpreted (at least I don't see how) as separate attempts that each either fail or succeed with a certain probability.

Comment: @user: Thus, while we can say that the expected number of keystrokes required in your scenario is $12\cdot30$, it doesn't make sense that the probability for each keystroke to succeed is $\frac1{12\cdot30}$. Also, in the first example, it's not true that the reciprocal $30^{12}$ of the success probability $\frac1{30^{12}}$ is the expected number of seconds / keystrokes you have to wait. It's the number of **attempts** you expect to make before succeeding, with each attempt consisting of $12$ keystrokes.

Comment: @user: You could stop when the initial keystrokes are wrong, but even then it'll sometimes be more than $1$ keystroke per attempt. By the way, I'm sorry about the unfriendly tone in my first comment above -- I was very stressed out when I wrote that; I shouldn't have replied in that mood :-)

Comment: No worries, you are the one teaching me, I am the one slow to understand